# NLP classifier to tag requirements written in unstructured text

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am looking for taggers or extractors that can identify passages of text that contain legal contract terms / requirements (e.g., *The agent shall provide...*) Most contract terms can be easily identified with RegEx but I am hoping there is something more sophisticated to catch edge cases (e.g., grammatically incorrect sentences, sentences without modal verbs).